# How to disable interpolation of property values in property placeholders

Tags: spring

I'm using Spring 3 and Spring's property-placeholders in my application context:

`<context:property-placeholder location="my.properties"/>`

my.properties contains:

```
key1=value1
key2=some JSP code ${some-model-attr}
```

The issue is, the *values* in `my.properties` are also evaluated against the placeholders, but in my case the values contain JSP EL, which causes "property not found" errors during Spring initialization:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'some-model-attr'
```

So far I have this workaround, but it's ugly:

```
key1=value1
key2=some JSP code #{'$'}{some-model-attr}
```

Hence my question:

*Is it possible to tell Spring not to interpolate property placeholder values, or, in other words, not to evaluate placeholders recursively?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it isn't possible to tell Spring not to recursively evaluate placeholders.

The placeholders are evaluated by `org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper` which (in Spring 3) contains the following line:

```
    // Recursive invocation, parsing placeholders contained in the placeholder key.
    placeholder = parseStringValue(placeholder, placeholderResolver, visitedPlaceholders);
```

So the recursive call is hard-coded into the evaluation.

However I think you could change the default prefix and suffix for placeholders so that you use a different syntax for Spring placeholders. `<context:property-placeholder>` is just a convenient way of constructing the `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class, and that class has methods `setPlaceholderPrefix()` and `setPlaceholderSuffix()`. You could use those methods to change the syntax of the Spring placeholders to something like:

```
$[property]
```

instead of

```
${property}
```

Then I expect Spring won't parse your JSP properties any more because they're in a different syntax:

```
key2=some JSP code ${some-model-attr}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you can use [SpEL expression templating](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-templating). For example:

```
key2=some JSP code $#{'{some-model-attr}'}
```

This works because Spring no longer sees the configured property placeholder prefix of `${`. However, the SpEL expression evaluates to the String concatenation of:

```
'some JSP code $' + '{some-model-attr}'
```

which is the same as

```
some JSP code ${some-model-attr}
```